# Design problem: Updating database from a low latency C++ application

Tags: c++, database, performance

I am developing a low latency application in C++. I also need to update the databases of my processing and all state changes. In order to save on latency involved in calling Database updates, I am using local data structures (in-memory) in my application.

But I still need to update databases also. Should I use a separate thread for updating databases? How can I save on database latency and still keep the databases up-to-date.

Comment: If you have provided more background info, it will be easier to help. What is your app? What are you storing in database?

Comment: do you need the DB updated in near real-time? if not, why not sync your local data periodically offline?

Comment: The application is a trading engine. I need to keep the DB updated and make it resilient to failure. A delayed DB update is allowed but cannot be missed. So, am looking for some kind of in-between layer where I can just dump the database update and continue (some other thread automatically updates to main database). IS there any solution of this kind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For minimal latency, you'll definitely want a database thread (I"ll call it DBT).
However, if updates are frequent, you'll want to buffer changes, and have the DBT merge whatever updates it can before they get pushed to the actual database.  If player.x = 1, then player.x = 2, the DBT can skip the first one.
If updates are very fast, and the data set isn't immense, you may consider regular full dumps instead of running updates.  Eg, like "saving" what you're doing every 60 seconds, instead of sending the database a list of every action done.
The answer would depend a lot on what you're doing.  There isn't a one-size-fits-all answer here.

Comment: I haven't had anyone with more than 100 rep say that before!

Comment: @Mooing: I'm not rep-picky ;)

Comment: A database thread (DBT) is exactly what I am looking for. Is there any ready-made solution for this? Pls share more thoughts on this.

Comment: @Ashish Grover: There's lots of threading libraries, like http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread.html.

Comment: As for implementing the database push, you'll probably have to write your own thread.  It'd be hard to find a library that specific to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is one definitely good solution: save to database as seldom as possible. You dont have to call saving every second, in most cases you can safely call DB once per minute or even less frequently.

Comment: No, this is not always wise. What if the data is mission critical and you need resilience to failure? Your process barfs or the sqld goes down, and you just lost all the data from the last minute (or even more).

Comment: If you do the low-latency things AND can't make long intervals between saves, you already know the solution, or else you won't get that job ;) I think the problem is related to gaming - in gaming, the loss of even ten minutes doesn't hurt much.

Comment: Yes, the database updates cannot be missed. They can be delayed but they need to be resilient to failure.

Comment: @Xirdus: "You should already know how to do this" is not a valid answer to this question. And what makes you think that this has anything to do with gaming?

Answer (score 0):

Combining the given answers and applying my own thoughts, I am thinking of implementing the following strategy:-
- On the fly, update the local data structure and dump to a file rather than database
- A separate thread for database will read from a file and dump it to database (actually will have to take a lock and move the existing file and copy the contents to database)

What you say?
Any loopholes in this solution above.